# SOAP header Action was not understood

Tags: c#, web-services, asmx, wshttpbinding, webhttpbinding

I am trying to consume a webservice in C#.  Whenever i try to  call the function  from the web service class I am getting a "SOAP header Action was not understood".I've added web reference[not service reference] pointing the web service in my project. The following steps were  taken to add the web reference

1) right click on the project -> Add WebReference

when i examined the web service in web browser i found this in the header

```
<wsdl:definitions name="MyService" targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/">
    <wsp:Policy wsu:Id="WSHttpBinding_ICAIService_policy">
        <wsp:ExactlyOne><wsp:All><sp:TransportBinding>
    <wsp:Policy>
```

I've done the following code to call the web service functions

```
WebStruct webS = new WebStruct();
webS.Name = "Peter";
webS.ID = 22;

webS.Find(webS);
```

Comment: How are `wsHttpBinding` and `webHttpBinding` related to your question? Web reference uses older ASMX API and it doesn't support services exposed on these bindings. Actually `webHttpBinding` is not supported by Add service reference as well.

Answer (score 5):

Remove the Web Reference and add a Service Reference instead.

Comment: yes this fixed the same error message for me. thank you.

Comment: This didn't fix for me. WsBinding doesn't understand these headers

Answer (score 4):

Try to use simple service endpoint binding BasicHttpBinding. This binding is compatible with .NET 2.0.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it really helped me.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check with your webservice provider? Seems they need some customized header information to process your request. Adding such headers by the service providers are very much common to increase the security.

Answer (score 0):

SoapAction errors only went away when I went into the "Configure Service Reference..." properties and updated the Service Reference with these options ticked.

and ticked these two boxes:

TICK  Generate asynchronous operations
TICK  Always generate message contracts